# Is it possible to grey out data on ListView in VB6?

Tags: listview, vb6

I'm creating a program that has a search facility. It works fine. If I enter an item in the search box it displays that item, if I leave it blank it displays al items etc.
My question is if I were to search for a particular product, would it be possible for the ListView to display the item at the top of the list and all other items after and greyed out if possible? I need all data so it can be copied to an external file.

This is my code at the moment. As I said it works fine but would it be possible as I need all items in the listview so my program can run properly. Thanks

```
 Dim desc As String
 Dim barcode As String
 Dim quantity As String
 Dim dept As String

 Dim listitm As ListItem
 Dim itm As ListItem
 Dim SearchStr As String
 Dim SearchChar As String
 Dim colhead As ColumnHeader

 ListView1.ListItems.Clear

 Open "E:\Latest VB\Export.CSV" For Input As #1
 Do Until EOF(1)
 Input #1, desc, barcode, quantity, dept
 If InStr(1, LCase(desc), txtProduct.Text, vbTextCompare) Then
 With ListView1
    .View = lvwReport
    .FullRowSelect = True
 Set itm = .FindItem(txtProduct.Text, lvwText, , lvwPartial)
 Set listitm = .ListItems.Add(, , desc)
 listitm.SubItems(1) = (barcode)
 listitm.SubItems(2) = (quantity)
 listitm.SubItems(3) = (dept)
 End With
 End If
 Loop
 Close #1
 End Sub
```

Comment: Ergh, please indent your code!

Comment: Maybe you could try FlexGrid control as it allows changing backcolor of the cells.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot grayout (disable) items, but you can change the forecolor to gray as if it was disabled by using the [Custom Drawing callbacks](http://btmtz.mvps.org/listview/) ([zip](http://btmtz.mvps.org/listview/lvcustomdraw.zip)).

Comment: U may use TAG also to flag if these items is disabled or not and check it on DoubleCick (if you use this event)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just grey out the text, and not disable it, then the following will work:

```
' Purpose: If a match for <the_sText> is found, then the first item matching is moved to the top of the control, and all the other items are greyed out.
Private Sub HighlightTextInListView(ByRef the_sText As String)

    Dim sKeyOfPreviousItem  As String
    Dim oListItemAtTop      As ListItem
    Dim oFoundListItem      As ListItem
    Dim nIndex              As Long

    Set oListItemAtTop = lvData.ListItems(1)
    sKeyOfPreviousItem = oListItemAtTop.Tag         ' We are storing the original previous item's key in the top item's Tag property.

    ' If it is set to non-empty string, the we know that it has been previous sorted to the top.
    ' Undo this before anything else.
    If sKeyOfPreviousItem <> "" Then
        MoveItem oListItemAtTop, lvData.ListItems.Item(sKeyOfPreviousItem).Index + 1
    End If

    If the_sText = "" Then

        ' If the search box is empty, then ungrey all the text.
        SetTextForeColor vbWindowText

    Else

        ' Look for the text.
        Set oFoundListItem = lvData.FindItem(the_sText, lvwText, , lvwPartial)

        If oFoundListItem Is Nothing Then
            SetTextForeColor vbWindowText
        Else
            SetTextForeColor vbGrayText

            ' Find the text in the previous item to the selected item (if none, use "").
            nIndex = oFoundListItem.Index
            If nIndex = 1 Then
                sKeyOfPreviousItem = ""
            Else
                sKeyOfPreviousItem = lvData.ListItems.Item(nIndex - 1).Key
            End If

            ' Move this item to the top of the list, and set its Tag property to indicate the previous item.
            ' Note that this new item will not have grey text.
            MoveItem(oFoundListItem, 1).Tag = sKeyOfPreviousItem

        End If

    End If

End Sub

' Purpose: Adds a new item to the list view.
Private Sub AddListItem(ByRef the_sKey As String, ByRef the_sDescription As String, the_sBarCode As String, ByRef the_sQuantity As String, ByRef the_sDepartment)

    With lvData.ListItems
        With .Add(, the_sKey, the_sDescription)
            .SubItems(1) = the_sBarCode
            .SubItems(2) = the_sQuantity
            .SubItems(3) = the_sDepartment
        End With
    End With

End Sub

' Purpose: Adds a new item with the same properties as the previous, at a specific position.
Private Function MoveItem(ByRef the_oListItem As ListItem, ByVal the_nNewPos As Long) As ListItem

    Dim oListItem               As ListItem
    Dim sKey                    As String

    Set oListItem = lvData.ListItems.Add(the_nNewPos, , the_oListItem.Text)
    oListItem.SubItems(1) = the_oListItem.SubItems(1)
    oListItem.SubItems(2) = the_oListItem.SubItems(2)
    oListItem.SubItems(3) = the_oListItem.SubItems(3)

    sKey = the_oListItem.Key
    lvData.ListItems.Remove sKey
    oListItem.Key = sKey

    Set MoveItem = oListItem

End Function

' Purpose: Set the fore colour of each list item.
Private Sub SetTextForeColor(ByVal the_cForeColor As OLE_COLOR)

    Dim oListItem               As ListItem
    Dim oSubItem                As ListSubItem

    For Each oListItem In lvData.ListItems
        oListItem.ForeColor = the_cForeColor
        For Each oSubItem In oListItem.ListSubItems
            oSubItem.ForeColor = the_cForeColor
        Next oSubItem
    Next oListItem

End Sub
```

Just use HighlightTextInListView() when ever you want to run the search. Essentially, I delete the item and re-add it at the top. To remember its old position, then the previous item's Key property is stored in the moved item's Tag property. For this code to work, you must give your items unique keys.